# Using pmap at specific changing levels with map_depth

Tags: r, purrr, pmap

I'm wondering if it's possible to apply `purrr::pmap` (`purrr::map2`?) combined with `purrr::map_depth`.

Let's say I have two lists with exact same structure with multiple nested lists, defined as:

```
  l1 <- list(
    list(0.0132),
    list(
      list(0.033, 0.066)
    ),
    list(
      list(
        list(0.165, 0.11, 0.06),
        list(0.165, 0.22, 0.12)
      )
    )
  )
  
  l2 <- list(
    list(0.6),
    list(
      list(0.75, 0.1)
    ),
    list(
      list(
        list(0.65, 0.71, 0.16),
        list(0.25, 0.98, 0.22)
      )
    )
  )
```

Is it possible to combine `purrr's` functions, (`pmap`, `map_depth`, `vec_depth`, etc) to apply some function but taking into account different depths?

Let's suppose I want to get the product `l1`*`l2`of each element between lists (e.g. `0.0132*0.6`, `0.033*0.75`, ...). Using same principle as I'd apply with `map2`, I have tried passing 3 arguments to pmap, `l1`, `l2`, `vdepth`, but I'm not able to get desired results.

```
vdepth <- map(l1, vec_depth)

pmap(list(l1, l2, vdepth), function(a, b, d) map_depth(c(a, b), d - 1, ~ FUN))
```

Final result should have same structure as any of the lists used as inputs.

PS: Not very fan of `unlist` and trying to stick to `purrr`'s functions...

Comment: I note you said you're not a fan of `unlist()` but you can do this elegantly with `unlist()` and `relist()`: `relist(unlist(l1) * unlist(l2), l1)`.  What's not to be a fan of??  A `purrr` solution is likely to be considerably more convoluted.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know if it is possible to make use of `purrr`'s tools, but your solution it's completely valid and much more simple, thank you.